Gradle Build can't find a dependency
I was trying to buld a github project, but I got an Could not find plus.dragons.createdragonlib:create_dragon_lib-1.19.2:1.0.2 error.
The project - https://github.com/mred231/CreateEnchantmentIndustry-Fabric/tree/1.19.2-f
The problem is that gradle can't find the dependency, even though it is there. Probably something here
repositories {
    maven { url = "https://maven.shedaniel.me/" } // Cloth Config, REI
    maven { url = "https://maven.blamejared.com/" } // JEI
    maven { url = "https://maven.parchmentmc.org" } // Parchment mappings
    maven { url = "https://maven.quiltmc.org/repository/release" } // Quilt Mappings
    maven { url = "https://api.modrinth.com/maven" } // LazyDFU
    maven { url = "https://maven.terraformersmc.com/#/releases/" } // Mod Menu
    maven { url = "https://mvn.devos.one/snapshots/" } // Create, Porting Lib, Forge Tags, Milk Lib, Registrate
    maven { url = "https://mvn.devos.one/releases/" } // Porting Lib Releases
    maven { url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Fuzss/modresources/main/maven/" } // Forge Config API Port
    maven { url = "https://maven.jamieswhiteshirt.com/libs-release" } // Reach Entity Attributes
    maven { url = "https://jitpack.io/" } // Mixin Extras, Fabric ASM
    maven { url = "https://maven.tterrag.com/" } // Flywheel
    maven { url = "https://maven.dragons.plus/releases" } // DragonLib
    maven { url = "https://maven.dragons.plus/snapshots" } // DragonLib snapshot
    mavenLocal() // Fast test
}
...
dependencies { 
    modImplementation("plus.dragons.createdragonlib:create_dragon_lib-${minecraft_version}:${create_dragon_lib_version}")
    }

I have no idea how to fix this, so i'm asking for help here.
Sorry if my English is bad, it's my second language

This question is similar to: Gradle alternate to mvn install. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

aled, it is entirely different. My problem is that a github project can't find what it is searching for. Problem you linked is in someone asking how to do something they did ith maven with gradle.

It is the same, because if the dependency is not found in public repository you need to install it in your local machine repository. That is what the link is about. You need to download the project, build it and install the dependency.

Nothing changed (Or i'm a bit dumb (No, i'm not))

After a few renames of files, it worked. Thanks
